# Conexión MQTT con React Native

Tags: ionic3, reactjs

Como hacer una conexión a MQTT con React Native, algun ejemplo...
Si no es con React Native puede ser en IONIC.
Quiero controlar IOT desde el movil.

Answer (score 1):

Paho es la libreria mejor documentada y más facil de usar, en el archivo Readme.md viene un ejemplo. Te permite crear un cliente y que este se suscriba/envie mensajes a tópicos MQTT.

```
import { Client, Message } from 'react-native-paho-mqtt';

//Set up an in-memory alternative to global localStorage
const myStorage = {
  setItem: (key, item) => {
    myStorage[key] = item;
  },
  getItem: (key) => myStorage[key],
  removeItem: (key) => {
    delete myStorage[key];
  },
};

// Create a client instance
const client = new Client({ uri: 'ws://iot.eclipse.org:80/ws', clientId: 'clientId', storage: myStorage });

// set event handlers
client.on('connectionLost', (responseObject) => {
  if (responseObject.errorCode !== 0) {
    console.log(responseObject.errorMessage);
  }
});
client.on('messageReceived', (message) => {
  console.log(message.payloadString);
});

// connect the client
client.connect()
  .then(() => {
    // Once a connection has been made, make a subscription and send a message.
    console.log('onConnect');
    return client.subscribe('World');
  })
  .then(() => {
    const message = new Message('Hello');
    message.destinationName = 'World';
    client.send(message);
  })
  .catch((responseObject) => {
    if (responseObject.errorCode !== 0) {
      console.log('onConnectionLost:' + responseObject.errorMessage);
    }
  })
;
```

**Es importante mencionar que requiere el uso de un broker que admita WebSockets de forma nativa, o el uso de un Gateway que pueda reenviar entre WebSockets y TCP.**

Te recomiendo primero correr el código de ejemplo para que entiendas el código y luego lo adaptes a tu aplicación. Puedes probar en tu misma pc creando un broker, un cliente suscrito a un topico y un cliente que envie mensajes a ese tópico, necesitaras 3 consolas. ¡Saludos!

Comment: es importante leer [answer] colocar respuestas solo con elnaces se considera de baja calidad

Comment: es necesario coloques el ejemplo del que hablas aquí, por que si ese enlace se rompe entonces la información no será útil ni visible para los demás